# before_validation issues with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

The problem is that I am using

```
def before_validation
  self.author.strip!
  self.author_email.strip!
end
```

and I get an error message:

DEPRECATION WARNING: Base#before_validation has been deprecated, please use Base.before_validation :method instead.

Can somebody point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Somewhere toward the top of your class model place the name of your clean-up method:

```
before_validation :remove_whitespace
```

... and then further down your model class place a private method with the same name:

```
def remove_whitespace
  self.author.strip!
  self.author_email.strip!
end
```

Optionally, if you want a one-liner, then you could also pass a lambda instead of a method name to before_validation:

```
before_validation lambda {self.author.strip!; self.author_email.strip!}
```

Answer (score 1):

per here 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Try something like this.  you can just call before_validation  and pass it a block as opposed to overriding it.

```
before_validation() do 
  self.author.strip!
  self.author_email.strip!
end
```